# How can I make a list of three sentences to a string?

Tags: string, list, nlp, svm

I have a target word and the left and right context that I have to join together. I am using pandas and I try to join the sentences, and the target word, together into a list, which I can then turn into a string so that it would work with my vectorizer. Basically I am just trying to turn a list of three sentences to a string.

This is the error that I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-ae09731d3572> in <module>()
      3 
      4 vectorizer=CountVectorizer(max_features=100000,binary=True,ngram_range=(1,2))
----> 5 feature_matrix=vectorizer.fit_transform(trainTexts)
      6 print("shape=",feature_matrix.shape)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     66     """
     67     if lower:
---> 68         doc = doc.lower()
     69     if accent_function is not None:
     70         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I have tried using `.join`and `.split` but they are not working for me so I am doing something wrong.

```
import sys
import csv
import random

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

trainLabels = []
trainTexts = []

with open ("myTsvFile.tsv") as train:
  trainData = [row for row in csv.reader(train, delimiter='\t')]
  random.shuffle(trainData)
for example in trainData:
  trainLabels.append(example[1])
  trainTexts.append(example[3:6])
```

The indexes `example[3:6]` means that the 3 is left context 4 is target word and 5 right context.

```
print('Text:', trainTexts[3])
print('Label:', trainLabels[1])
```

edited the few printed lines from the code:

```
['Visa electron käy aika monessa paikassa luottokortista . Mukaanlukien ', 'Paypal', ' , mikä avaa taas lisää ovia .']

['Nyt pistän pääni pölkyllä : ', 'WinForms', ' on ihan ok .']
```

Comment: Could you please share a few lines from the  "myTsvFile.tsv" so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added two random annotations from the file. They are not in English but I assume that should not matter. Paypal and WinForms are the target words in the text.